# Is there a way to return a python variable to php?

Tags: python, php, search-engine

So I am making a search engine to search the internet and the engine is powered with python and the webpage for the results is in php. I need to take variables (namely, the `filelist` list) and return them to the php script. Please excuse any typos.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='searchengine.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $cmd='python3 searchresult.py'+$_POST["searchquery"];
        $output = shell_exec($cmd);
        echo $output;
        ?>
        
    </body>
 </html>
```

is the php code.

```
import sys
from os import listdir, basename
import re

keyword=sys.argv[1]
keyword=str(keyword)
filelist=[]
db='C:\\Users\\monik\\Documents\\searchengine\\db'
filestoparse=listdir(db)
for file in filestoparse:
    with open(file,  'r') as f:
        filecontent=str(f.read)
        result=re.findall(keyword, filecontent)
        if len(result)>=5:
            filelist.append(basename(f.name))
```

is the python code.

Comment: shell_exec should capture StdOut from the python script. Try adding a print statement to the end of your script: `print(filelist)`

Comment: In PHP, you concatenate strings using `.` and not `+` so it should probably be `$cmd='python3 searchresult.py' . $_POST["searchquery"];`. However, executing user data directly into shell_exec() is dangerous. Always escape the data first: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php. You're also not passing the data as an argument to your python file, you're actually adding the search to the filename of the python file. You need to have a space after `.py`.

Comment: To Mike67:  I do not need to display the output, i need to return the value to the php script

Answer (score 1):

You may write your `filestoparse` to a json file and then read you json file with php.

> Python

```
import json 
#parse files in directory to dictionary 
filestoparsetodict ={'file1':'myfile.cdr', 'file2':'picture.psd'}

# write your dictionary to json file
out_file = open("C:/xampp/htdocs/phpjson/myfile.json", "w") 
json.dump(filestoparsetodict, out_file) 
out_file.close()
```

> PHP

```
<?php
$filelist = file_get_contents("myfile.json");
// Convert content to array 
$myarray = json_decode($filelist, true);
echo $myarray["file1"]; // print an item from array objects
?>
```

Comment: _Side note:_ jQuery is just a library build in JS so if you use jQuery, you're using JS so the "or" is a bit misleading here. Also, instead of just giving an abstract answer, you should show some real example to show what you mean.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, Is this better?